# nginx + unicorn + sinatra + paperclip, failed to allocate memory

Tags: memory, file-upload, nginx, sinatra, unicorn

I deployed a Sinatra Ruby app with nginx and unicorn and I'm getting a "failed to allocate memory" when uploading large files (About 300MB or more). I'm currently using paperclip to upload images along with with datamapper(MySQL). Client-side, I'm using jQuery-file-upload by blueimp. My server is the cheapest digital ocean machine, which has 512MB RAM, but I don't understand why this process is taking up my RAM (Don't uploads get stored by parts in a temp file and then moved to the final destination?). I want to understand how the upload process works and how to get around this problem in my current 512MB RAM server. I hope you guys can help me.

Upload code:

```
post '/client/create/media' do
    file_hash = params["files"][0]
    title = params[:title][0]
    description = params[:description][0]
    if (fileAllowed())
        paperclip_hash = make_paperclip_hash(file_hash)
        begin
            mediaObject = Mediaobject.create(:file => paperclip_hash, :client => Client.get(session[:id]), 
                                            :random => SecureRandom.hex(16), :name => title[0..49], :type => type.to_s, 
                                            :description => description)
        rescue Exception => e
            puts e.message
        end
    else
        #nothing
    end
end
```

MediaObject class:

```
class Mediaobject
    include DataMapper::Resource
    include Paperclip::Resource

    property :id,           Serial
    property :name,         String, :length => 64
    property :type,         String
    property :description,  Text
    property :random,       String, :length => 32 

    belongs_to :client

    has n, :containers, :through => Resource

    has_attached_file :file,
                    :url => "/client/media/:id",
                    :path => "#{Dir.pwd}/media/:userid/:random-:id.:extension"
end
```

The error occurs when creating the MediaObject instance and it says "failed to allocate memory" only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to do the upload manually, without paperclip, and it worked just fine. So paperclip seems to be the problem here.